# Mongoose - remove items from DBref array and item itself

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a schema that looks a bit like:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
   created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   comments: { type: [Schema.ObjectId], ref: 'Comment' }
});
```

So my comments collection, is a collection of object id's referencing my comment schema / collection.

I need to remove some of them on query, so i'm trying this:

```
var comments = [1, 2, 4];    

Post.update({ _id: post_id}, {'$pullAll': {comments: comments }})
  .exec(function(err) {
     // How to remove documents with 1, 2, 4 ids from a Comment collection properly
});
```

After executing the code above I've removed an ids of comment  from a Post.comments but I need to remove these comments from a 'Comments' collection also. How should I do that?

**EDIT:** How can I get ids of documents which were not removed in fact. The simple example:

```
Post.comments = [1, 2, 3]; 
Post.update({ _id: post_id}, {'$pullAll': {comments: [1,2]}});
```

In the code above a Post.comments has 1,2,3 only, but we are trying to pull [1,2], so I need to know that id=3 is not exists in Post.comments and I don't need to remove it from 'Comments' collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$in`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) operator for that:

```
var comments = [1, 2, 4];    

Post.update({ _id: post_id}, {'$pullAll': {comments: comments }})
  .exec(function(err) {
    Comment.remove({ _id: { $in: comments }}, function(err, numberRemoved) {
      // The identified comments are now removed.
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command to issue the update and return the original document in the `value` property of the command result. You should have no problem comparing the returned `comments` field with the ID's from your `$pullAll` query to discern which ID's were actually removed.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0-rc1
connecting to: test
> db.posts.drop()
true
> db.posts.insert({ _id: 1, comments: [1,2,3] })
> db.runCommand({
... findAndModify: "posts",
... query: { _id: 1 },
... update: { $pullAll: { comments: [1,2,4] }},
... })
{
    "value" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "comments" : [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    "lastErrorObject" : {
        "updatedExisting" : true,
        "n" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

As JohnnyHK mentioned in his answer, removing the comment documents themselves is best done with a `remove()` query and `$in` operator.

Note: my above example uses the Mongo JS shell. It looks like Mongoose recently got a helper method for `findAndModify` (see: [PR #803](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/803)), although you could always execute the database command if that's not available in the version you're using.